# Cómo editar la información de un formulario dinámico con javascript y php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html5

Hola buenas noches qué tal?, Tengo una duda y espero contar con su apoyo para resolverla. Veran, no se como explicarlo bien, ya que es algo complejo; estoy aprendiendo a programar en php-javascript-sql, por medio de un curso y nos dejaron de tarea aplicarle dinamismo con javascript a unos formularios basados en campos select multiples, y tener la opción de "agregar información" y "editar información reciente".

He creado un formulario y luego he guardado ese formulario en dos archivos diferentes. El primero digamos que es el que se cargara cuando le de click a un botón llamado: "agregar información nueva"; allí me aparecera el formulario pero digamos que vacío, para que pueda seleccionar valores y luego guardar la información en una base de datos(esta parte la tengo hecha sin ningun problema).

El segundo archivo sera el que se cargara si le doy click al botón: "Editar información reciente"; para este caso, necesito que me aparezca el mismo formulario pero con la información que había guardado con el formulario anterior, para que pueda editar esta información y guardar los cambios. 
Es en esta parte donde tengo dudas y me he lidado mucho, porque se como hacer esto con campos input tipo text, number, etc pero no se como hacerlo con elementos select multiple. Cómo hacer para que al entrar en la opción de editar información reciente me aparezca el formulario con los elementos select y que la información que guarde en el formulario anterior me aparezca en este formulario pero con atributo "selected"?

Yo he intentado hacerlo de esta manera: 
Extraer los datos de la base de datos(los datos que guarde previamente con el primer formulario), guardar esos datos en variables php ($primero) y luego por medio de javascript (función changeValues(); ) tratar de hacer que esos datos aparezcan como opciones seleccionadas en los elementos selects multiple.
Tengo dos archivos php:  el primero se llama "agregar_info.php" y contiene el formulario para agregar información nueva. El segundo se llama "editar_info.php", 
El código que mostrare a continuación forma parte del archivo "editar_info.php" (es solo una parte del código que tiene ese archivo, es solo para mostrarles lo que estoy tratando de hacer):

codigo php:

```
$sentencia = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE  fecha = '$date'");
while ($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia)) { //se utiliza el while para ir guardando todos los elementos de la consulta.
    if ($extraido !== null) {
        $primero = $extraido['sun']; //la información que se almacena en esta variable es la que quiero pasar a una variable javascript.
        $fecha = $extraido['fecha'];
    } }//  llave de cierre para el while


mysqli_free_result($sentencia);
mysqli_close($link);
```

```js
var none = true;
function changeValues () {

  var sunUpdate = $("#sun_id").val() || [];
  var recibidos = <?php echo $primero; ?>; 
         $("#sun_id").val(recibidos); 
         sunUpdate = $("#sun_id").val()
       var sunTexts = $("#sun_id option:selected").map(function() {
           return $(this).text();
                                }).get();   

 //esta parte son validaciones que le realizo al formulario, me funciona bien en el primer formulario(agregar información nueva), pero para este formulario de editar información, estas validaciones no están funcionando bien.
 
//primera validación
  if(sunUpdate == "") { //si no hay ninguna opción seleccionada se realizan las siguientes acciones

    $("#sun_id").val("0"); //se asigna coloca la primera opción como "selected".
    
    sunUpdate = $("#sun_id").val() // Se Actualiza los nuevos valores seleccionados
    
    $('.sun').css("font-weight", "normal");
    sunTexts = $("#sun_id option:selected").map(function() {
                  return $(this).text();
                                }).get(); //Se Actualiza el texto de las opciones seleccionadas
    none = true; //se establece que la primera opción esta seleccionada
    $('#sun_id').material_select('destroy'); //se destruye el select para poder efectuar los cambios
    $('#sun_id').material_select(); //se construye el select con los cambios realizados.
  }

 
//segunda validación
  if (none && (sunUpdate.length > 1 || sunUpdate[0] != "0")) { // si la primera opcion del select esta seleccionada pero se selecciona algo diferente
     
    $("#sun_id option[value=0]").removeAttr("selected");
    // se actualizan los valores seleccionados
    sunValues = $("#sun_id").val()
   
    $('.sun').css("font-weight", " bold");
    sunTexts = $("#sun_id option:selected").map(function() {
                  return $(this).text();
                                }).get();
  
        none = false; //se establece que la primera opción ya no esta seleccionada.
        $('#sun_id').material_select('destroy'); //se destruye el select
        $('#sun_id').material_select(); //se reconstruye el select

  } else if (!none && sunUpdate.indexOf("0") > -1) { //si las opciones con value = 1, 2 o 3 estan seleccionadas pero se selecciona la opción con value 0
 
    $("#sun_id").val("0"); //se asigna la primera opcion como "selected"

    sunUpdate = $("#sun_id").val() //se actualizan los valores
 
    $('.sun').css("font-weight", "normal");
    sunTexts = $("#sun_id option:selected").map(function() {
                  return $(this).text();
                                }).get();

    none = true;
    $('#sun_id').material_select('destroy');
    $('#sun_id').material_select();
  }

  document.querySelector('.sun').innerHTML = sunTexts.join(", "); 
//se muestran los valores seleccionados en un elemtento span
  $('.sun').html(sunTexts.join(", ")); 

    }
    $("#sun_id").change(changeValues); //se aplica evento change
    changeValues();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
          
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.collapsible').collapsible();
      });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready (function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
    $('select').material_select('destroy');
</script>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <span class="sun"></span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="colores">
            <!-- este es el elemento select -->
            <select id="sun_id" multiple="multiple" name="sun[]" class="sunMultiple">
              <option value="0">None</option>
              <option value="1"> Sunny</option>
              <option value="2">Partly sunny</option>
              <option value="3">Not sunny</option>
              
            </select>
              <label for="sun_id">Select Conditions</label>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que intento hacer es colocar los valores extraidos de la base de datos como valores seleccionados en el select, y lo logro pero el problema esta cuando quiero editar, o sea seleccionar otros valores o deseleccionar los que estan, al final siempre me quedan los valores que he extraído de la base de datos. Creo que el problema esta en la función js.

Cómo podria solucionar ese problema? Lo que quiero es que sea un formulario para editar la información guardada anteriormente, para poder deseleccionar los valores que había guardado previamente y seleccionar otros, o dejar unos y colocar otros, asi sucesivamente.

Los errores que pasan son, por ejemplo: 
En el primer formulario yo selecciono a guardar la opción "Sunny", esto lo hace correctamente. Luego voy al formulario de editar información y me aparece inicialmente la opción Sunny como selecionado, eso esta muy bien pero si por ejemplo intento desmarcar esa opción y elegir otra, entonces esa opcion me aparece marcada igual, no se quita. Se supone que hay unas validaciones en javascript que deben cumplirse, pero no estan funcionando. 
Alguna idea como podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres hacer en ese PHP?, porque no has definido **$primero** y tampoco es un array como para que después lo uses en implode(). Aparte, tampoco se ve que generes una salida html ni json.

Comment: Por favor estructura mejor al respuesta. Trata de mejorar el primer parrafo, dividelo en parrafo más pequeños y si es posible se un poco mas concreto explicando el problema. Es una sugerencia para que más usuarios se interesen en contestar a tu pregunta. Un Saludo!

Comment: Edite la pregunta a ver si se entiende un poco mejor.